# Primefaces dataTable reset after Submit button click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am working with springboot + primefaces project and there is a page, which include a form. form is to update trieved data, form has some input fields and datatable, how ever after i click submit button datatable value reset in first attempt, but after enter value and click submit second attemp success.this issue affect only for datatable not for other entries.

```html
<h:form id="editForm" style="font-size: 13px;">
    <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="6" style="margin: 14px 0px;">

            <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Name English"/>
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{detailsController.details.name}"
                         required="true">
                <f:validateLength maximum="100"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="name"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable id="editFundSrc"  var="fundSrc" value="#{detailsController.fundSrcDetails}"
                         widgetVar="fundsrcTable"
                         emptyMessage="No Fund Source Available"
                         style="font-weight:bold;width: 600px; font-size:13px;text-align:left;background-color:#F3F1F6">
                <p:column headerText="" styleClass="tblColumn" width="30">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{fundSrc.enableSource}">
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fund Source" styleClass="tblColumn" width="60">
                    <h:outputText value="#{fundSrc.sourceName}" style="width:55px; font-weight:normal;  font-size:11px;"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Min Limit" styleClass="tblColumn" width="50">
                    <p:inputNumber value="#{fundSrc.minLimit}" style="width:45px; font-weight:normal;  font-size:11px;" modifyValueOnWheel="false"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Max Limit" styleClass="tblColumn" width="50">
                    <p:inputNumber value="#{fundSrc.maxLimit}" style="width:45px; font-weight:normal;  font-size:11px;" modifyValueOnWheel="false"/>
                </p:column>

         </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%">
            <p:commandButton class="btn right-btn" value="#{editTxnDetailsController.btnLabel}"
                             actionListener="#{editTxnDetailsController.resubmitWorkflow}"
                             update="editForm,editFundSrc"> 
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```